# get field value by its name in java

Tags: java, reflection

i need to read the field value given the field name. say i have class called product, it has fields: size, image, link.. and have methods as getSize(), getImage() and getLink() to read those values. now if i give 'size', i want to get size by calling getSize(), given 'image', get image by calling getImage()...

right now i have a clumsy code call getField(String fieldName) to handler this:

```
public void String getField(String fieldName, Product p) {
   String value = "";
   swtich(fieldName):
      case 'size':
         value = p.getSize();
         break;
      case 'image':
         value = p.getImage();
         break;
      ....
```

problem is i have too many fields in this class, the whole code looks ugly. also i try to avoid the reflection page because of the poor readability.  is there any other idea to handle this nicely? thanks

Comment: The only alternative is reflection.

Answer (score 1):

Other than reflection or an explicit switch (as you have), the only real alternative is to not have those fields at all. Instead of `getSize()`, `getImage()`, etc., you could just have a general-purpose `getAttribute(Attribute a)`. `Attribute` there would probably be an `enum`. Something like:

```
enum Attribute { SIZE, IMAGE, ... }

public class Product {
    Map<Attribute, String> attributes = new EnumMap<>(Attribute.class);

    public String getAttribute(Attribute attribute) {
        return attributes.get(attribute);
    }

    public void setAttribute(Attribute attribute, String value) {
        attributes.put(attribute, value);
    }

    ...
}
```

`EnumMap`s are very efficient, so this code will be speedy -- not quite as speedy as real fields, but probably not noticeably slower in your app.

The reason for making `Attribute` an `enum` (rather than just having `String` attribute keys, for instance) is that it gives you the same type safety as explicit getter functions. For instance, `p.getAttribute(Attribute.NOT_A_REAL_ATTRIBUTE)` will produce a compile-time error, same as `p.getNotARealAttribute()` would (assuming that enum value and method aren't defined, of course).

Comment: I believe Google's Protocolbuffer does something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider to use directly attribute names as keys of map and values as attributes.

`HashMap<String, Object> attributes`

Thus you don't have to modify your structure or enum if new attributes are added.

Beware, "Size" and "size" will be behaved differently.